# Match pattern non-greedily around pattern

Tags: regex, notepad++

Given the input string:

```
a
a
bcx
ada
ac
```

the expression `a.+?c` (`a` and `c` are not necessarily single letter tokens) results in 2 matches:

```
a
a
bc
```

and

```
ada
ac
```

when I only really want:

```
a
bc
```

and

```
a
ac
```

Basically, I want the smallest matching parts possible. How do I achieve this in Notepad++?

Comment: Which tool or programming language are you using?

Comment: @blhsing Notepad++. OP updated

Comment: That does not match those unless `s` flag is set.

Comment: You probably need `a[^ca]*c`

Comment: How about: `a\R.+?c`

Comment: Is it only single letters? Edit your question to have real test cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex with negative lookahead in `DOTALL` (or `s`) mode:

```
a(?:(?!a.+c).)+?c
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ufMLby/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `a`: Match a letter `a`
- `(?:(?!a.+c).)`: Match a letter if not followed by expression `a.+c`
- `+?`: Match 1 or more of preceding group (non-greedy)
- `c`: Match a letter `c`

**PS:** This pattern can be easily adapted if you are not really dealing with single letters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an exclusion character set to ensure there isn't another `a` after the first `a`, except for the character before `c`:

```
a[^a]*?.c
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/u9YRqC/1

Comment: If input string is `abpqrdefghacc` then this regex will match `abpqrdefghac ` and my regex will match last `acc`. Not sure which is wanted by OP :)

Comment: Indeed, without the context behind the OP's problem it is unclear how the test case you presented should resolve.

Comment: @anubhava Apologies for an insufficient example. I would want `acc` in your example.